# VBA Error in referencing range of another sheet via the Cells option

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, formatting

I have some subs I use to format data in an Excel file. 
In particular, I have a sub that I can activate in the sheet("1.Parus") that has the line :

`Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(1000, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)`

But I have another sub to be activated in another sheet, where I want to be able to reste formatting in several sheets. And I get an error when trying this :

`Worksheets("1.Parus").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(1000, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)`

Whereas code like :  `Worksheets("1.Parus").Columns("J:L").EntireColumn.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)` works fine.

I am a bit lost as to what does not work, and the available help I have found is not specific enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a syntax issue : the `Worsheets("W1").` only applies to the immediately following object. Therefore,

`Worksheets("1.Parus").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(1000, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)` should be

`Range(Worksheets("1.Parus").Cells(2, 1), Worksheets("1.Parus").Cells(1000, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)`